# performSegueWithIdentifier if-statement not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've got 6 diffident tables and when the row in one of them is selected (in the regionsFirstTable it matters which one) I want them to perform a segue. The code for regionsFirstTable works fine, but as for the other part it doesn't - the segues are just not working. I know it's too messy, but the answer should be laying on the surface.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == self.regionsFirstTable) {
    {     if (indexPath.row==0)
        if (indexPath.section==1) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAfricanFS" sender:indexPath];
        } else {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAfricanFS" sender:indexPath];
        }
        if (indexPath.row==1)
            if (indexPath.section==1) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAsiaFS" sender:indexPath];

            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAsiaFS" sender:indexPath];
            }
        if (indexPath.row==2)
            if (indexPath.section==1) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toEuropeFS" sender:indexPath];

            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toEuropeFS" sender:indexPath];
            }
        if (indexPath.row==3)
            if (indexPath.section==1) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toLatinFS" sender:indexPath];
            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toLatinFS" sender:indexPath];
            }
        if (indexPath.row==4)
            if (indexPath.section==1) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNorthAmericaFS" sender:indexPath];
            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNorthAmericaFS" sender:indexPath];
            }
    } //Dealing with the first UITableView, it works

    if (tableView == self.africaFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromAfricatoDone" sender:indexPath];
    } 
    if (tableView == self.asiaFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromAsiatoDone" sender:indexPath];
    } 
    if (tableView == self.europeFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromEuropetoDone" sender:indexPath];
    }
    if (tableView == self.latinAmericaFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromLatintoDone" sender:indexPath];
    } 
    if (tableView == self.northAmericaFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromNorthAmericatoDone" sender:indexPath];
    } //This whole thing is not working as it should be
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. All my tables have only one indexPath.section

Comment: Is there anymore information you can provide? It doesn't sound like you're getting any exceptions. If you set a break point starting on the line: "self.africaFirstTable", are any of these if statements resolving to true? If so, have you confirmed that the segue id's are spelled the same as in your storyboard?

Comment: The names are right, I copied them from the Storyboard, and even if I leave the first statement and comment out the others, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you hitting a break point though where you expect the segue to be performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have too many `{`s after your first `if`, so all your checks for `if ( tableView == self.northAmericaFirstTable)` aren't hitting because it is all nested within the `if (tableView == self.regionsFirstTable)` block

EDIT:

Here is the fixed code, theoretically

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (tableView == self.regionsFirstTable) {
     if (indexPath.row==0)
        if (indexPath.section==1) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAfricanFS" sender:indexPath];
        } else {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAfricanFS" sender:indexPath];
        }
        if (indexPath.row==1)
            if (indexPath.section==1) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAsiaFS" sender:indexPath];

            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toAsiaFS" sender:indexPath];
            }
        if (indexPath.row==2)
            if (indexPath.section==1) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toEuropeFS" sender:indexPath];

            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toEuropeFS" sender:indexPath];
            }
        if (indexPath.row==3)
            if (indexPath.section==1) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toLatinFS" sender:indexPath];
            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toLatinFS" sender:indexPath];
            }
        if (indexPath.row==4)
            if (indexPath.section==1) {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNorthAmericaFS" sender:indexPath];
            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNorthAmericaFS" sender:indexPath];
            }
    } //Dealing with the first UITableView, it works

    if (tableView == self.africaFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromAfricatoDone" sender:indexPath];
    } 
    if (tableView == self.asiaFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromAsiatoDone" sender:indexPath];
    } 
    if (tableView == self.europeFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromEuropetoDone" sender:indexPath];
    }
    if (tableView == self.latinAmericaFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromLatintoDone" sender:indexPath];
    } 
    if (tableView == self.northAmericaFirstTable) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromNorthAmericatoDone" sender:indexPath];
    } //This whole thing is not working as it should be
}
```